# Parsing nested json to display data

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display the data using this json and from the values of the "contact" key build a drop-down menu, I can't figure this one out:

json data:

```
data =     [
  {"conta":"13356","name":"MISS Two"},
  {"zip":"01111","city":"NASHUA, MA","street_a":"10 MAIN ROAD SQUARE","street_b":"Nothing"},
  {"count":"544","number":"250"},
[
  {"contact":"Mark Bre"},
  {"contact":"Mary Lou"},
  {"contact":"John Ton"},
  {"contact":"Carls Des"},
  {"contact":"Carlos Drt"}
 ]
]
```

Any help, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

using recursive way to iterate through data;[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zehYP/1/)

```
   function showData(obj){
   for(var k in obj){
       if($.isArray(obj[k])){
            showData(obj[k]);
        }
         else{
             for(var l in obj[k]){
                $('body').append(obj[k][l]+ "   ");             
             }
             $('body').append( "<br>");
           console.log(obj[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this code to work, how can I display the dropdown menu on the page?

Answer (score 0):

create select..append it to the element you want (i am appending it to body)... loop through your data.. create options amd append it to the created dynamic select

try this

```
$('body').append('<select id="dynamicSelect"></select>');
var options="";
$.each(data,function(i1,val1){
       if($.isArray(val1)){
          $.each(data,function(i2,val2){
               options += "<option value="+ val2.contact +">" + val2.contact + "</option>"
          });
       }
    }
$('#dynamicSelect').append(options);
```